# bootstrap code in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

i try this code to display responsive image in my post in wordpress using bootstrap but image doesnot respond to bootstrap effect..i actually include all bootstrap files in my theme directory just fine

```
<article class="media">
     <h2>About the venue</h2>
        <img class="pull-left img-responsive" src="wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/hotels/contempo.jpg" alt="Hotel Contempo"/>
           <p>All CAC speaking events located at 309 1st Avenue, in Downtown Seattle..</p>
  </article>
```

does this method work fine or there is something wrong??if not..is there  other ideas???

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that img-responsive is designed to scale to the parent element. Your parent element is just "media", which isn't a bootstrap class with any defined width. Change the class (or add) one of the bootstrap grid elements and you should have no issues with the image inside scaling.